# В какую степень нужно возвести число 2, чтобы получилось число n?

Tags: c#, математика

В какую степень нужно возвести число 2, чтобы получилось число n? 
Например, число n = 8, т.е. 23. Как узнать эту степень?

Производительность приветствуется, но и не главное - лучше пожертвовать скоростью и сделать код понятным (я нуб в программировании, а всякие побитовые операции для меня - темный лес).

Comment: В математике это называется логарифм по основанию 2. Он же двоичный логарифм. В принципе у вас в языке должны быть встроенные функции для этого. Если конечно у вас не стоит задача сделать это самостоятельно. Тогда искать какой самый старший бит числа установлен в 1 (для целых чисел)

Comment: Условие задачи нечетко поставлено. Является ли `n` целым числом? Гарантируется ли, что число `n` является степенью двойки? Если не гарантируется, то какой нужно получить результат? Округленный? Или дробный?

Comment: `всякие побитовые операции для меня - темный лес`  - ну вот, пришло время познакомиться с ними. Нельзя же всю жизнь только "ключи подавать" © ;)

Comment: Необходимо сдвигать побитово влево, я не знаю на каком языке вы пишите, но к примеру C# если не ошибаюсь, вот так будут: x << 1; По вашей теме, следует почитать операторы сдвига, у Г. Шилдта (если все же C#) это 4 глава. Там подробно все описано.
Там кстати как раз ваш пример описан)

Сноска:

x << 1 - умножить х на 2 в первой степени

x >> 1 - разделить х на 2 в первой степени

Соответсвенно: x << 2 - умножить x на 2 во второй степени.

Удачи!) И там снизу коммент, с решением вашей задачки)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ответы с точки зрения математики уже дали, дам свой с точки зрения программирования.

Если число является степенью двойки, то оно представляет собой единицу и последовательность нулей. Можно сдвигать единицу влево, пока число не станет равным заданному, а потом вернуть количество сдвигов (`power` в коде ниже).

```
// 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 1000 0000
int n = 128;
// 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0001
int i = 1;
int power = 0;

while (i < n)
{
    // сдвигаем единицу на 1 бит влево
    i <<= 1;
    // увеличиваем счетчик степени
    power++;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Прологарифмировать.

Если
[image: введите сюда описание изображения],

то

[image: введите сюда описание изображения].

А вот их основные свойства:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3):

С помощью логарифма

log2(8) = 3